# Time complexity of Sieve of Eratosthenes

Tags: algorithms, time-complexity, primes

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes#Algorithmic_complexity) states that the Sieve of Eratosthenes runs in time $O(n\log\log n)$. Why is that so?

Comment: Follow the algorithm and see how many operations it will perform. It is "a direct consequence of the fact that the prime harmonic series asymptotically approaches log log n

Comment: At least you should be able to write the number of operations as a sum.

Comment: @gnasher729 Why _prime harmonic series asymptotically approaches log log n_ ? I have read the proof on that link, but I am still confused.

Comment: Doesn't the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes#Computational_analysis) contain the answer?

Answer (score 1):

Write a sum for the number of operations of removing multiples of primes. How many operations to remove all multiples of 103 for example from an array of n bits? How many operations to remove all multiples of a prime number p? So you get a sum.

Then you need to know what the sum 1/1 + 1/2 + 1/3 + ... + 1/n is (roughly) and importantly *why*. You see that by adding 1/1 + (1/2 + 1/3) + (1/4 + 1/5 + 1/6 + 1/7) + (1/8 + 1/9 ... + 1/15) + ... and there is an obvious upper bound.

Now instead of adding 1/k for $2^m ≤ k < 2^{m+1}$ you add 1/k for only the *primes* k with $2^m ≤ k < 2^{m+1}$. How many are there? What sum do you get now? And then you have a sum that looks almost exactly like the one you started with and gives you the result.

Comment: **by adding 1/1 + (1/2 + 1/3) + (1/4 + 1/5 + 1/6 + 1/7) + (1/8 + 1/9 ... + 1/15) + ... and there is an obvious upper bound.**  <-- Huh? How obvious is that ?

Comment: The first is 1. The second is two numbers <= 1/2 therefore <= 1. The third is four numbers <= 1/4 therefore <= 1. The next is 8 numbers <= 1/8 therefore <= 1.

Comment: but that still does not tell why  time complexity = O(n*log(log n)) ?

Comment: Paragraph 3 of my answer. You need to do a bit of work yourself.

Comment: Why  add 1/k for only the primes k with 2^m ≤ k < 2^(m+1)   ?

Comment: Because you only remove multiples of primes. And that’s for primes in one interval. Add up for all m.